# Return an array of selected structs or values picked from an array of structs

Tags: solidity, arrays, solidity-0.8.x

Lottery time!
At every new lottery initialized, each User is given n tickets.
All the participants tickets are registered in a mapping called "allEntered" which collects tickets from *every* lottery.
How do I return user's tickets for a given Lottery ID?

```
uint256 public currentLottery = 3;

struct Ticket {
        uint256 ticket_id;         
        address ticketOwner;
        uint256 lottery_id;  
    }

mapping(address => Ticket[]) public allEntered;
```

I wished to cycle through all user's ticket, check if lottery_id == currentLottery and in that case push the Ticket (or the ticket ID) in a new array to be returned. But it would be a dynamic memory array, which is not possible in Solidity.
Code:
Let's assume I already know the qty of user tickets because I've been smart when distributing them (although it would be nice to have a way to retrieve this number dynamically).

```
//This doesn't work because "push" is for dynamic arrays
function getMyCurrentTickets() public view returns(Ticket[] memory){
        Ticket[] memory myTk = new Ticket[](myKnownQty); //I wish this length was retrieved or dynamic
        for(uint i; i<allEntered[msg.sender].length; i++){
            if(allEntered[msg.sender][i].lottery_id == currentLottery){
                myTk.push(allEntered[msg.sender][i]);
            }
        }
        return myTk;
    }

//This doesn't work either because produces blank entries in the returned array
function getMyCurrentTickets() public view returns(Ticket[] memory){
        Ticket[] memory myTk = new Ticket[](allEntered[msg.sender].length);
        for(uint i; i<allEntered[msg.sender].length; i++){
            if(allEntered[msg.sender][i].lottery_id == currentLottery){
                myTk[i] = allEntered[msg.sender][i];
            }
        }
        return myTk;
    }
```

It's one whole day I'm struggling with workarounds but then I have the problem to reset the workarounds, and you cant just delete mappings, but this is another problem... Any ideas to help a noob?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying another route right now: a mapping of that mapping.

```
mapping (uint256 => mapping(address => Ticket[])) public lotteries;
//where the main unit256 key is the lottery_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMyCurrentTickets() public view returns(Ticket[] memory) {
    uint256 ticketCount;
    Ticket[] memory tempTk = new Ticket[](allEntered[msg.sender].length);
    
    // First, filter the tickets and populate the temporary array
    for(uint i = 0; i < allEntered[msg.sender].length; i++) {
        if(allEntered[msg.sender][i].lottery_id == currentLottery) {
            tempTk[ticketCount] = allEntered[msg.sender][i];
            ticketCount++;
        }
    }
    
    // Now, we create a new array with the exact length as there are tickets
    Ticket[] memory myTk = new Ticket[](ticketCount);
    for(uint i = 0; i < ticketCount; i++) {
        myTk[i] = tempTk[i];
    }

    return myTk;
}
```

This function works in two steps:

1. It loops over all the tickets and fills up a temporary array while counting how many tickets belong to the current lottery.
2. It then creates a second array with the size of the count of relevant tickets and copies the tickets over.